# M1 Related! - Prisma: Can't reach database server at `database`:`5432`

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, prisma, apple-m1

Since I have moved to the new Apple Silicon architecture my docker setup with nextjs and postgres is not working anymore. The database inside the docker cannot be found by the nextjs server where I am using prisma.

The prisma client can't reach the postgres database on port 5432.

> Can't reach database server at `test-postgres`:`5432`

The migration also does not work and returns the same error above.

```sh
docker-compose run --publish 5555:5555 next npx prisma migrate dev
```

docker-compose.yml

```
postgres:
    container_name: 'test-postgres'
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: 'postgres:13'
    ports:
      - '15432:5432'
    volumes:
      - 'pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

.env

```
DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:15432/postgres"
```

I have also added the arm binary target to the schema.prisma
schema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets   = ["native", "debian-openssl-1.1.x", "linux-arm-openssl-1.1.x", "linux-musl"]
  previewFeatures = ["orderByRelation", "selectRelationCount"]
}
```

The postgres container is actually running and I can see it through the Docker Desktop Dashboard. One thing I have noticed inside the postgres container was this ERROR:

```
2021-07-21 12:52:58.927 UTC [76] ERROR:  relation "_prisma_migrations" does not exist at character 126
```

Have someone experienced it before and found a solution for it?

[EDIT]

#### How to reproduce

clone repo, follow README.md and see expected behaviour on a M1 Apple Silicon Machine: https://github.com/baristikir/prisma-postgres-M1

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Adding `?connect_timeout=300` to the connection string of the database did the trick.

```
DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:15432/postgres?connect_timeout=300"
```

Comment: nice, worked for me

Comment: Got this error for two weeks now, thank you so much!

Comment: It definitely does the trick. No idea why though.

Comment: Dude, literally, I was looking for this like 4 hours or smth, thx

Comment: No way, how can this work? And it has 36 upvotes. How adding a connection timeout can solve the problem? Can you explain??

Comment: It works! Without knowing what's the cause. Thank you.

Comment: that's my champion

Comment: It doesn't work with my mariadb database (I'm using ssl). Fails instantly on my device when I add the option and on vercel it always times out instantly, too. However on my device it works if I don't specify anything.

Comment: We were setting up our backend with prisma in 8 kubernetes pods
Since we made so many connections at one go, it was timing out, and only ~4 pods were able to connect at one go.

In our case, this param makes a lot sense, since it increased the timeout for connection from 30s to 5mins, and it worked!!!

Comment: All hail the saviour. Hallelujah

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue on m1 mac mini, **the solution was changing the version of node from v16.16.0(image node:16) to v17.9.1(node:17), we tried on node:18 it works also**.
I changed Dockerfile
from

```
FROM node:16
```

to

```
FROM node:17
```

Comment: 17 alphine version isn't working. must be 17 version 

Comment: I spent so much time trying to figure this out. Im on an m2 mac book air, this fixed my issue for good. More people should be able to find this when they need it. thank you so much for this comment.

Answer (score 2):

I was using 16.17.0 version of Node.
Just switched back to 16.13.2 and the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I added `?connect_timeout=300` and it worked.
I realized it's taking some time, before connecting to the database especially when it's from a cloud provider, therefore the error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33141226)

Answer (score 0):

With me I just change the database URL:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root:root@<My IP>:5432/<MY DB Name>"
```

And it works fine.

Comment: What is "My IP"? Your public local IP or 127:0.0.1 ?

Comment: It's "Your public local IP" hope to help u.