# Cloud Functions - PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `my.cloudsql.ip`:`3306

Tags: google-cloud-functions, prisma

Im trying to deploy my NodeJS app to Google cloud functions connected to a Cloud SQL instance (MySQL) and using Prisma ORM.

The deployment was successful, but whenever I access an API route with a connection to the database, I get the following error as a response:

`` PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `my.cloudsql.ip`:`3306`. Please make sure your database server is running at `my.cloudsql.ip`:`3306`. ``

My database string looks like this: `"mysql://user:password@cloud-sql-ip/database?host=/cloudsql/instance-connection-name"`

I alread try adding `?connect_timeout=300` to the connection string of the database as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68476229/m1-related-prisma-cant-reach-database-server-at-database5432). But I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also took me a while to figure this out, here's the URL that worked for me:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP}:3306/{DB_NAME}?socket={INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}
```

Then, in your schema.prisma:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "MySQL"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

ALSO, remember to update the IAM permissions in your Cloud Function/Cloud SQL instance to authorize the Cloud function to read from DB:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Updating my IAM permissions in my Cloud Function instance to authorize the Cloud function to read from DB worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, It is because I use the generated password from cloud SQL .Thus, I encode it and my connection string is like

> DATABASE_URL=mysql://{USER:{PASSWORD}@{INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP}:3306/{DB_NAME}