# Can't connect to Postgres CloudSQL from Prisma in Cloudfunction

Tags: postgresql, authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, prisma

I'm trying to connect to a public IP CloudSQL Postgres database from a cloud function with Prisma.
The database has SSL enforced. I assume I can use the Cloud Auth Proxy, and it works locally, but when I deploy it gives me an error.

I've tried both:

**Option 1:**

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = "postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:3307/DATABASE_NAME?host=CONNECTION_URL"
}
```

Got error:

```
Can't reach database server at `CONNECTION_URL`:`3307`
```

---

**Option 2:**

```
datasource db {
      provider = "postgresql"
      url = "postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@localhost/DATABASE_NAME?host=CONNECTION_URL"
    }
```

Got error:

```
Can't reach database server at `IP_ADDRESS`:`5432`
```

Where IP_ADDRESS is the correct public IP address for the database that I can see in the console

CONNECTION_URL is /cloudsql/PROJ:REGION:INSTANCE

Comment: check suggestions in this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72118668/cloud-functions-prismaclientinitializationerror-cant-reach-database-server-a), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72500709/18265638),[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68495296/18265638)

Comment: Link1 and link2 are for MySQL, tried it but doesn't work. Link3 doesn't work either

Comment: can you check the format of the connection string as mentioned in this [github](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/14013#issuecomment-1169146188)

Comment: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`. Doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Figure out I had the vpc connector enabled to all traffic, so all traffic was trying to go through the private VPC instead of the public IP. Disabling it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use connection similiar a this:
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://username:pass@localhost/databasename?host=/cloudsql/full-instance-connection-name"

full-instance-connection-name = xxx:us-central1:xxx

The full-instance-connection-name, can be found in your GCP by searching for SQL, you will see all the database instances you have, just add the one you need to connect to.

This resolve my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer - what you have to do:

Have a public IP and configure full network access with:
`0.0.0.0/0` under Connections > Networking
[image]

Afterward you can use a string like this:

```
postgres://USER:PASSWORD@localhost/DB_NAME?host=PUBLIC_IP
```

Make sure you password only contains ASCII chars to not break the URL.

Comment: Although this answer will work, it is strongly discouraged. The solution opens access to the Cloud SQL instance to the world. The recommended solution is the Cloud SQL Connector: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector

Answer (score -1):

You application is trying to connect on "CONNECTION_URL" and "3307". To use public IP on Cloud Functions you should by connecting by unix socket: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#connect_to

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-client-js/issues/437), it looks like your URL should be something like:

```js
postgresql://username@localhost/databasename?host=/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME
```

Where your instance connection name is `PROJ:REGION:INSTANCE`.

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't specify in the original post but with CONNECTION_URL I meant  /cloudsql/PROJ:REGION:INSTANCE. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Does removing the 3307 help?